# Inserts to multiple HTML Tables

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Pretty new to asp MVC, i have a view which contains multiple HTML tables, my question is how do i pass the data from these tables to my controller, the data passed will be going into the same SQL table

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have 3 tables and each table has some input controls, then your MVC Action should accept an instance of a class, this class should have a public property for each input control in your HTML.

ex:
assuming you have the following HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="ProductName" value=" " /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="ProductPrice" value=" " /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="ProductDescription" value=" " /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then your Action parameter should be similar to:

```
public class FormData
{
  public string ProductName{get;set;}
  public string ProductPrice{get;set;}
  public string ProductDescription{get;set;}
}
```

And your action should be:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(FormData form)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(form);
    }
```

The more tables and controls you add, the more properties you will have to add to your `FormData` class, if you want to add grouping, then you can add sub classes into the `FormData` class and prefix the property name in the HTML with it.

Comment: Only problem with this is, there a lot of controls, therefore we will have a lot of properties, was looking for a cleaner solution if there is any